# how to store multiple selected dropdown values in database in codeingiter

Tags: codeigniter

i have two tables in my database one is requirements another one is users..i have those user names in my requirements form with select box..how to store that user names id in database..

This is my **view**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Choose  Vendor</label>
  <select  class="form-control"  multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="user name"  name="user_id[]" >
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php foreach($user as $rows) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rows->user_id?>"><?php echo ucfirst($rows->first_name)?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is my **controller**:

```
public function requirement()
{
  $data["msg"]="";
  $this->load->model('RequirementModel');
  $data['user']=$this->RequirementModel->getusers();
  if($this->input->post())
  {
    $this->RequirementModel->add_requirement($this->input->post());
    redirect(base_url('index.php/Login/dashboard'));
  }
  $this->load->view('Requirements/requirements',$data);
}
```

This is my **model**:

```
function getusers()
{    
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  //echo $this->db->last_query();
  return $query->result();
}
```

model **add_requirement**:

```
public function add_requirement($data)
{
  $data=array('role_name'=>$post['role_name'],'vacancies'=>$po‌​st['vacancies'],'exp‌​erience'=>$post['exp‌​erience'],'jd'=>$pos‌​t['jd'],'hiring_cont‌​act_name'=>$post['hi‌​ring_contact_name'],‌​'hiring_contact_numb‌​er'=>$post['hiring_c‌​ontact_number'],'use‌​r_id'=>$user_id);
  $this->db->insert('requirements', $data);
}
```

how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: want to store user names?

Comment: no that particular usernames id's

Comment: where is `add_requirement` function?

Comment: there will be multiple user ids?

Comment: ha yes..i want to store multiple user id's in requirements table

Comment: you can store it comma separated or you have to make separate table to store it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function `add_requirement` like below and try;

```
function add_requirement($data)
{
  if(isset($data['user_id']) && !empty($data['user_id'])) {
    $data['user_id'] = implode(',',$user_id);
  }

  $data=array('role_name'=>$post['role_name'],'vacancies'=>$po‌​st['vacancies'],'exp‌​erience'=>$post['exp‌​erience'],'jd'=>$pos‌​t['jd'],'hiring_cont‌​act_name'=>$post['hi‌​ring_contact_name'],‌​'hiring_contact_numb‌​er'=>$post['hiring_c‌​ontact_number']);
      $this->db->insert('requirements', $data);
  }
}
```